# Alias name in having clause in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5

I'm using a function which is using alias name in "HAVING" clause and I'm getting an error,

**"Unknown column 'orderStatusWithoutOpen' in 'having clause'"**.

Here is my code:

```
public static function getEquipmentPaginated($conditions = false, $id = false,$orderby='equipment_no',$order='asc',$filter=false)
{
    $equipment = Equipment::select('checklist.*'); 
    $equipment->leftjoin('checklist','equipment_id','=','equipment.id');
    $equipment->addSelect('equipment.*', DB::Raw("(SELECT count(ordre.status = 001) FROM ordre LEFT JOIN checklist ON checklist.ordre_id=ordre.id WHERE checklist.equipment_id=equipment.id and ordre.status = 001 order by ordre.start_date desc limit 1) AS orderStatusWithoutOpen"));        
    $equipment->groupBy('equipment.id');

    $start = date('Y-m-d');
    $end = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+15days'));

    if($filter == '1' && $filter != "") {
        $equipment->having('orderStatusWithoutOpen', "<", $filter);
    }

    if($filter == $start) {
        $equipment->whereBetween('certificate.valid_date', [$start, $end]);
    }

    if($id) {
        $equipment->where('equipment.customer_id', '=', $id);
    } 
    return $equipment->paginate(10);
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what mistake I'm making here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I corrected this myself. The query is working good and problem is with the pagination. So what I did is, I return the result within the if condition where I'm using 'HAVING' clause. Like Mentioned below:

```
if($filter == '1' && $filter != "") 
{
    $equipment->having('orderStatusWithoutOpen', "<", $filter);
    return $equipment->get();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bring the value in select query on which you want to order the result.

For example if **equipment_fabricat.fabricat_name** THEN 
get that value in **select(equipment_fabricat.fabricat_name)** before applying order by

Comment: Actually that's not the prob. I get "orderStatusWithoutOpen" as unknown column;though I mentioned this column in select method.

Comment: COALESCE((SELECT count(ordre.status = 001) FROM ordre LEFT JOIN checklist ON checklist.ordre_id=ordre.id WHERE checklist.equipment_id=equipment.id and ordre.status = 001 order by ordre.start_date desc limit 1),'')

Comment: try above if no value is found then it will take empty string as orderStatusWithoutOpen instead of null